# SQL Server : conversion error when using INSERT INTO SELECT with JOIN with identical source/destination database

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do a migrate some data from an old database to a blank copy of the same database. Both has identical table structures and datatypes. However I am getting a conversion error, yet in my script there is no datatype conversion since both tables are identical. Below is my SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO [TEST_NEW].[dbo].[RESULT] 
    SELECT 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].SAMPNO', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].ACODE', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].ANALYTE', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RESULT', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RESULT2', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].QUALIFY', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].MDL', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].VIOLTYPE', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].VIOLVALUE', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].VIOLDATE', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].VIOLUSER', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RLTNUM', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RMODDATE', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RMODUSER', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].DILFACTOR', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RAWRESULT', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].STARTDATE', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].ENDDATE', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].ANALYST', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].hSec', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].PQL', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RAWMDL', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RAWPQL', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RLTUNIT', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RLTSOURCE', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].REPLNUM', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RESULTPART', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].RESULTCHECKSUM', 
        '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].CHECKSUMVERSION', '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].AREF'
    FROM 
        [TEST].[DBO].[RESULT]
    INNER JOIN 
        [TEST].[DBO].[SAMPLE] ON [TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].SAMPNO = [TEST].[DBO].[SAMPLE].SAMPNO
    WHERE 
        [TEST].[dbo].[SAMPLE].SSTATUS IN ('I', 'C')
```

Error from SQL:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '[TEST].[dbo].[RESULT].VIOLTYPE' to data type smallint

Comment: Remove these single quotes around the column names.

Comment: Single quotes turn the column names to strings, hence the conversion error.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Could forpas or @GMB  please write up the answer.